# Firefox open Save as dialog to the default location

Tags: firefox

I'd like Firefox's "Save as" dialog to always open at the same location, and I'd like it to be my Desktop, so I can type the name of the folder I want to save the file in into the File Name box and then just hit Enter to confirm the choice.

To me, that would be the quickest way of saving files to folders of my choice, and all I need for that is that Firefox doesn't remember the last folder I saved a file to.

I've searched on the internet for solutions but I can't seem to find one.

Does anyone know how to fix the download location in Firefox to Desktop?

Comment: I don't know the answer you asked for, but it may interest you to know that you can go up a folder using `..`, even in the Safe File dialog. So, for example, let's say you have folders `AAA`, `BBB`, and `CCC` on your desktop. If you last saved into `AAA` and want to put the next save in `CCC`, you can do it by specifying the path as `..\CCC\<filename>`.

Comment: Thank you CBHacking, that is close to what I want, I wouldn't mind typing in dots and right slash but I'd also need to retype the file name, and I'd like to avoid it and reduce the whole downloading procedure to simply typing the name of the folder and hitting Enter twice.

Comment: Turns out you don't need the file name after all; it will set the default file name again. I'll add an answer.

Comment: Thank you CBHacking, if I can get away without typing anything other than the dots and slash, and the folder I want to save the file to, that would do for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can navigate upward as well as downward when specifying folders. If all your destination folders are siblings (that is, they are all immediate children of the same folder, such as Desktop) you can type `..\<foldername>` and just hit **Enter** twice; the first one will open the specified folder *"go to the parent of the current folder, then go to `<foldername>`"* and the second will save the file in that directory with the default name.

Note that this will work even if you're already in the folder you want to save in; it'll just bounce up to the parent and then back into that location. It's a few extra characters to type each time, but at least you can use them consistently.

Comment: It works, I must have been typing something wrong before, sorry. I may try to automate the procedure with an autohotkey script, and reduce mouse clicks and typing even more. Thank you for the help!

Comment: I've tried to make an autohotkey script and realized that this approach has a few drawbacks. First, I'd need to exclude Desktop as a location for which the script would send commands.As you said CBHacking, if the folders are immediate children of Desktop it will work, but If I last saved a file on Desktop the ..\ command won't work because it sends me one level up from there. Also, I realized that saving files to folders that are not on Desktop is something that I often do, so making a script only for the folders that are on Desktop is little help.

Answer (score 1):

#### I'd like Firefox's Save as dialog to always open at the same location, the Desktop

1. Goto "Options" > "General"
2. Select Downloads "Save files to"
3. Click "Browse" and select "Desktop"

   [image]

Comment: Thank you DavidPostill, but I want to have Save as dialog open on the fixed location, and then type in the name of the folder in the File name box, so I can save files to folders of my choice. I don't want files to be always saved at Desktop, I want Desktop to be the fixed location of the Save dialogue